# Single-phase motor and speed control with used parts

Tags: motor, motor-controller, appliances, reuse

Asking for a friend who is intending on setting up a one-off, custom-built appliance for a farm. He needs a motor and control scheme for "rotary impact cleaning". It should be:

- Low-cost (insofar as that's possible)
- Accuracy and efficiency do not matter whatsoever, direction doesn't really matter either
- Three-phase is unavailable so he's stuck with 110VAC single-phase
- Has rudimentary speed control - either continuous or multi-setting
- Is "reasonably powerful", perhaps 500W
- Can handle unpredictable mechanical load
- Target RPM up to perhaps 300 RPM

Commonly-available used parts are preferred if possible, but new parts are not ruled out completely. Custom circuitry is fine if needed.

I've seen controllers for sale that convert a single-phase supply to a lines controlling a three-phase motor, and that's OK in principle, but these controllers were somewhat expensive.

My questions are:

- What kind of control scheme (phase or inverter control, etc.) is appropriate here?
- Are there any common types of appliances or automotive systems, etc. viable as used sources for such a system?
- Failing used parts, what category of new parts should I be looking at - motors with integrated speed control, or a separate controller, etc.

Comment: This is a matter of searching for what is available and comparing prices and specifications. Nothing that you have describes provides a reason for preferring one control scheme over another.

Comment: Hard to say without a target power in Watts or HP rating and expected RPM.

Comment: For cheap a treadmill DC motor, for better reliability a VFD and 3-phase motor, but it really depends on a lot of unstated factors. Something that runs 24/7 will have different needs for something that is rarely in motion, and as Jack says, HP and RPM and required start torque, speed regulation etc. figure into it. Maybe even a hydraulic motor would end up on top.

Comment: What will the motor used for?

Comment: No scheme for controlling a single-phase AC motor will be suitable for any load other than a fan or centrifugal pump. If it is a fan or pump, the performance will be strongly dependent on a close match between motor and load. If you value your time and need reliability, don't use anything used, improvised or sold without documentation.

Comment: Use a three phase motor, and a VFD that takes single phase input, or a 90 or 180 V DC motor and a small DC drive.

Comment: 300 RPM is going to be difficult without some type of mechanical speed reduction. The rated speed for the most commonly available AC motors is about 1750 RPM at 60 Hz. It might not be too difficult to find an 1150 RPM motor rated 500 W / 3/4 Hp. Below that, it will be difficult to find and more expensive. With a VFD, you could reduce the speed to below 300 RPM. But power is reduced in proportion to speed. If you never need to go above 300 RPM, you buying a 1150 RPM, 500 W motor and using it for 130 W. The motor will run hot at low speed also.